# Starvation prevention in priority queue

Tags: algorithm, priority-queue, starvation

As everyone knows, a priority queue can create starvation for lower priority items in its simplest form. For example, assume that we have following items in a priority queue in increasing priority order:

```
Item     Priority
--------------------
Item A      0      //Lowest priority
Item B      1
Item C      2
Item D      3
Item E      4      //Highest priority
```

Now if we receive a consistent flow of items with higher priority in our priority queue(B-E), we may never handle lower priority packets(A). I wonder what algorithms are there to handle this problem?

A simple approach that comes to my mind is limiting processing of different item types based on priority. For example, we limit packet processing of each type to `2 ^ priority`. So for table above, after handing 16 items of `Item E` type, we will handle up to 8 items of type `Item D`, up to 4 of `Item C`, up to 2 of `Item B` and up to 1 of `Item A` before starting to handle `Item E` again. This will prevent starvation for different item types.

This is a simple method, but I wonder if there are other famous algorithms to tackle this problem. Any idea for better algorithms or solutions?

Comment: May be [Aging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aging_(scheduling)) could help.

Comment: Look into MLFQ as well

Comment: thanks for suggestions. After reading about algorithms, I now think if changing priority (like Aging or MLFQ) is better than limiting number of processed packets or not. Is there any benefits for doing so?